# How set router in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

In my app i've a menu and any option is mapped with uri in a router.
In the view of log page there are two optinos:one to log-in and another to open a new view to sign-up,the prolem is:when i go to the sign-up view the url remain the same as previous log page.This is normal because there are no map in the route but it's correct?

The view log-page:

```
           var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

   template: Handlebars.compile(template),

  events: {
  "click .log_in":"log_in",
  "click .sign_up": "signUp_manual"
  },

 initialize: function() {this.render();},

   render: function() {

      var html =this.template();


      $('#pagina').html(this.$el.html(html));//appendo ad el);

      return this;
    },


    signUp_manual: function(){
     console.log("signup");
      new SignupView();  

    },


    log_in:function(){
        console.log("login");
       var username = this.$("#login-username").val();
        var password = this.$("#login-password").val();
        Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: function(user) {
        console.log("login riuscito");
         window.location='index.html'  ;//METTERE UNA NEW APPVIEW MA DA ERRORE!!!
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
       console.log("login non riuscito");
        }
       });

      }


    //inserire funzione per log-in


   });

    return LoginView;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave like that, but if you want to update the URL when someone clicks on the signup view you can do this is your model:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('mydomain.com/signup', {trigger: true});
```

Comment: Technically not, but thats standard. Unless you have the signup form as a pop-up.